# How to use Offline queuing in AWS IoT Core?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass

I'm attempting to implement offline queuing in AWS IoT Core using the aws-iot-device-sdk in Node.js. However, it appears that the functionality is not functioning as expected. Specifically, when attempting to publish several messages and subsequently disconnecting the device from the internet, upon reconnecting, the device fails to send the queued messages. I've experimented with setting the qos parameter to 1 in the publish method's options, but the issue persists. Any insights or suggestions on how to address this challenge would be greatly appreciated.